# hook add_action('wp_head') running when file not found

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing a plugin for WordPress to set a cookie and track it in a database.

```
function my_tracker() {
   // blah blah blah 
}

add_action("wp_head", "my_tracker");
```

For some reason, the tracker is called when a file is not found (ie. a hidden image file or unnecessary JS/CSS reference) on a resource linked from a post or page, which creates a duplicate value.

How does one prevent this? Is there a different hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

404 errors are handled by Wordpress, and have a default template as well, with its own header. So your  `wp_head` action gets triggered nonetheless.

You can use the [`is_404()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_404) to detect if Wordpress thinks the request is a "not found", and use it to return early in that case. E.g.:

```
function my_tracker() {
   if (is_404()) {
     return;
   }

   // and then blah blah blah 
}
```

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Comment: @JoeC, tru dat! I was in a hurry and kinda annoyed. Fixed that. Thanks!